# Associativity of a semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, associativity

I have the following problem. Let
$$
0\to A\to G\to Q\to 1
$$
be a central group extension with $A$ abelian. Assume that this extension splits, i.e., $G\cong A\rtimes Q$.

Now consider an action of another group $H$ on $G$ in such a way, that $H$ fixes $A$. In this case, it $H$ acts also on $Q$ in a way 'coherent' with the extension above. Under this assumption there is another extension of the form:
$$
0\to A\to G\rtimes H\to Q\rtimes H\to 1.
$$

Now the question I have is: since the first extension is split, does it follow that the second extension is? In other words, do we have that $(A\rtimes Q)\rtimes H\cong A\rtimes(Q\rtimes H)$?

I am pretty sure this is not true, so I would be very grateful for some nice counterexample!

Comment: What do you mean by central group extension.  I think if a central group extension splits then the middle group of the extension isomorphic to the direct product of the kernel group  A and the quotient group Q.

Comment: Isn't $D_8$ a counterexample? It is $(C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_2$, fixing one of the $C_2$s (which will be the centre), but it is not $C_2\rtimes (C_2\rtimes C_2)$.

Comment: Geez, of course. For some reason I was blind and assumed that the extension $C_2\to C_2\times C_2\to C_2$, where the first map is the diagonal, doesn't split. But it does! So your counterexample is easy and good enough. Thanks!